# Is it possible to send data to two different scripts?

Tags: php, html, forms, post

Simple html question. Is it possible to send data from html forms, like normal using "action" to two different scripts? Or is there any other way to do that? Besides using curl.

Answer (score 3):

use jquery to fire off two ajax calls to two seperate scripts..

```
$('#button').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: 'script1.php'
  });
  $.ajax({
    url: 'script2.php'
  });
)};
```

that's the quick and dirty way of doing it... Obviously add in error checking and success checking for both of them, in order to make sure both were submitted properly.

The ideal way is to use cURL, it avoids having js/client side issues, as well as avoiding an additional http request that's not necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Why not send it to one script that then sends it to the desired functions to process it?

Answer (score 1):

The normal action attribute cannot do that, but you could easily do that with Javascript. I can't provide much of an example without seeing some code though.

```
form.onsubmit(function(){
   senddata(here);
   senddata(there);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**An idea :**

- Send data from the form to script A
- Get script A send the data to script B (once it receives it)

Comment: Hey im sending it outside my code so I dont have acces to these two scripts